# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, split, null, typeerror

I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null" when trying to use the buy button that is connecting to my smart contract. I am reusing code from another project & dev. Can someone advise me on what direction to go in next?

```
 function gPOAookie(name) {
        var dc = document.cookie;
        var prefix = name + "=";
        var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);

    console.log(prefix, begin); 

    if (begin == -1) {
            begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);

            console.log(prefix, begin);
            if (begin != 0) return null;

            console.log(prefix, begin);
        }
        else
        {
            begin += 2;
            var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
            if (end == -1) {
            end = dc.length;

            console.log(begin, end);
        }
     }

     return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}


function fund (address, amount) {

    console.log("funding :" + amount);

    //  alert(gPOAookie('masternode'));

    if (walletMode === 'metamask') {

        contract.buy(gPOAookie('masternode').split(';')[0], {

            value: convertEthToWei(amount)
        }, function (e, r) {
            console.log(e, r)
        })
    } else if (walletMode === 'web') {
         call(address, 'buy', [], convertEthToWei(amount))
    }
}
```

You can view console log and Ui here 
https://hypereth.net/hyperexchange.html

Comment: Figure out why `if (begin != 0) return null;` is called. `dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);` is probably not `0`.

Comment: Can you please explain further? 
Are you saying that it should be returning something other than null?

Comment: I'm saying that it probably returns null and then you are calling split on it, which I guess is not the intended behavior?

Comment: so the intended behavior is when on the UI users can enter in amount ETH they want to spend and in return get tokens. Users have "referral" links which they get a % of the buys and sells of users that use their referral link. 

So my knowing limited coding I am seeing this is tied to cookies. I assume to log the cookie so the app knows the referral link used to fund the referrer.

Comment: when on the site https://hypereth.net/hyperexchange.html in the console log is where I see the error come up when I click the buy button and its pointing to this 

contract.buy(gPOAookie('masternode').split(';')[0], {

Comment: this seems to be working just fine on the site that I copied the code from. which is apexone.io/exchange.html so I am trying to recreate that. Do you think I am missing something?